# How to create fieldset collection using form factory in zf2

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I'm trying to create a form that contains a collection of fieldsets using only array specs and `Zend\Form\Factory`.

Here is how I create the form using the factory:

```
$factory = new Zend\Form\Factory();
$fieldset = $factory->createFieldset(array(
    'elements' => array(
        array(
            'spec' => array(
                'name' => 'name',
                'type' => 'Text',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control input-sm',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Name',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'spec' => array(
                'name' => 'driverClass',
                'type' => 'Text',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control input-sm',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Driver',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'input_filter' => array(
        'name' => array(
            'required' => true,
        ),
    ),
));
$form = $factory->createForm(array(
    'name' => 'application-form',
    'attributes' => array(
        'role' => 'form',
    ),
    'elements' => array(
        array(
            'spec' => array(
                'type' => 'Collection',
                'name' => 'connection',
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Connections',
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_remove' => true,
                    'should_create_template' => true,
                    'count' => 2,
                    'target_element' => $fieldset,
                ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'spec' => array(
                'name' => 'security',
                'type' => 'Csrf',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'required' => 'required',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'spec' => array(
                'name' => 'submit',
                'type' => 'Submit',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Apply',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

The resulting form works fine when I try to set data and render form elements. But when I validate it and retrieve data, like so (in a controller):

```
$form->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost());

if ($form->isValid() === true) {
    $data = $form->getData();

    var_dump($this->getRequest()->getPost());
    var_dump($data);
}
```

With this set of data as POST:

```
object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)[141]
  private 'storage' (ArrayObject) => 
    array (size=3)
      'connection' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              'name' => string 'orm_default' (length=11)
              'driverClass' => string 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' (length=36)
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              'name' => string 'blog' (length=4)
              'driverClass' => string 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' (length=36)
      'submit' => string '' (length=0)
      'security' => string '20d5c146d8874dc804948e962d5de91b-87c9e4097f9140d259efb5c589a05d6b' (length=65)
```

The array returned by the call to `$form->getData()` shows an empty collection:

```
array (size=3)
  'security' => string '20d5c146d8874dc804948e962d5de91b-87c9e4097f9140d259efb5c589a05d6b' (length=65)
  'submit' => string '' (length=0)
  'connection' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

What am I missing?

The expected result is a collection, named 'connection' in this example, containing two arrays representing the two fieldsets as specified by the POST data. I have a feeling this has to do with a missing InputFilter (or at least its specs) because I have managed to obtain the expected result when I implement a fieldset class that extends `Zend\Form\Fieldset` and implements `Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface`.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered this class `Zend\Form\InputFilterProviderFieldset` which does exactly what I missed.

I added a type in the fieldset specs and changed the input filter specs (which is mandatory) like so:

```
$fieldset = $factory->createFieldset(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\InputFilterProviderFieldset',
    'elements' => array(
        array(
            'spec' => array(
                'name' => 'name',
                'type' => 'Text',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control input-sm',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Name',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'spec' => array(
                'name' => 'driverClass',
                'type' => 'Text',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control input-sm',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Driver',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'input_filter_spec' => array(
            'name' => array(
                'required' => true,
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

And it works fine now. Hope this helped someone.